Optimizing Raster Data Display in Vue.js Frontend with Flask Backend for Improved Performance
The issue
I'm working on a web application where the frontend is built with Vue.js and the backend is powered by Flask. The core functionality involves displaying raster data on the frontend. Currently, the Flask backend processes raster data and passes list of point coordinates associated to values (e.g. temperature or rainfall) to the Vue.js frontend for rendering. However, I've encountered performance issues, particularly slow dialogues (240 ms) when displaying this data, especially with larger raster datasets. It wouldn't be a particular problem if it should load only one raster every once in a while, but there is also the possibility for the user to move a slider back and forth. This makes the experience very laggy.

A timing detail of a single response taken from DevTools
Current Implementation
My Flask backend reads raster data and converts it into a series of point coordinates. These are then sent to the frontend via a REST API. The Vue.js frontend uses these points to render the raster data on a map.
For the showcased application, we’ve chosen a compromise between detail and performance by setting the resolution at 500x500 meters across a 2000 km² area. This resolution strikes a balance, offering sufficiently detailed data to observe and analyze climate trends without overwhelming the system's capacity or the user's ability to interpret the data effectively. I'm not willing to lower the resolution to (say) 1000x1000 meters or similar.
For the current implementation the file transferred is 2.0 MB, it is a json including a list of Points with longitude and latitude coordinates, like in this case:
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "temperature": 24.5434
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    4.358284226273628,
                    50.8066121067541
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "temperature": 24.5543
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    4.365377876311481,
                    50.80661194844204
                ]
            }
        },
...
many other points
...
}

So my objective is to significantly improve the performance of raster data display in the frontend while ensuring minimal loss of data quality and user experience.
I'm seeking advice on:

Strategies for optimizing the processing and transfer of raster data from Flask to Vue.js. Would preprocessing or data compression be beneficial?
Recommendations for frontend technologies or libraries that integrate well with Vue.js for more efficient raster data rendering.
Any best practices for handling large datasets in a web application environment that spans both frontend and backend.

I appreciate any insights, code snippets, or resource recommendations that could help optimize this data handling and rendering process. Thank you!
